# How to run java client server with socket on eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I have run Java client server socket programs on CMD where you open different command prompt but I don't know how to run it in Eclipse. Is there is setting to run two programs at once?

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse it's fairly similar. Run the main class of both client and server. There is a an option to switch between console views. It will be a small computer monitor icon near the bottom. Click on it and you can view the list of main classes that are running and switch accordingly.